# Need the value (subtraction of value) to effect the value of another input

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to the value of money_due and have the value for deposit subtracted from it if the deposit input is holding a value. So far, it is adding it on just fine, but it is not removing it when I empty the value.

```
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Total Sum Due <span class="note">2</span></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="document.money_due" placeholder="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Deposit <span class="note">2</span></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" @change="hasDeposit" v-model="document.deposit" placeholder="">
        </div>
      </div>

    data() {
      return {
        now: new Date().toISOString(),
        document: {
          deposit: '',
          money_due: '',
        }
      }
    },

this.document.deposit = this.listing.price;
this.document.money_due = this.document.last_month + this.document.security_deposit,

    methods: {
      hasDeposit() {
        if(this.document.deposit == '') {
          return this.document.money_due = this.document.money_due + this.document.deposit;
         } else {
           return this.document.money_due = this.document.money_due;
        }
      },

    mounted() {
      this.hasDeposit();
    },
```

Comment: The desired functionality isn't really clear. If `money_due` is 1000 and the user enters 100 for the `deposit` then presumably you'd want `money_due` to drop to 900. What would happen if the user then changes that value from 900 to 1500 (with the 100 still in the other box)? What about if the user then changes the 100 to 200? Then 300? You're going to need to spell out precisely what the expectations are here when the user changes the numbers.

Comment: @skirtle If the user adds any amount into deposit (or if the default value is in deposit), it should add it onto the total for money_due. If the deposit is empty, it should not populate anything but the last_month and security_deposit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but it's a bit unclear what you want to achieve with your code.

I created a snippet where I tried to model the **deposit** and the **money_due** relations.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    listing: {
      price: 10
    },
    document: {
      last_month: -20,
      security_deposit: 10,
      deposit: 0,
      money_due: 0
    },
  },
  computed: {
    hasDeposit() {
      return Number(this.document.money_due) + Number(this.document.deposit)
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.document.deposit = this.listing.price;
    this.document.money_due = this.document.last_month + this.document.security_deposit
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label>Total Sum Due <span class="note">2</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="hasDeposit" placeholder=""></label><br />

  <label>Deposit <span class="note">2</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="document.deposit" placeholder=""></label>
</div>
```

1. I mocked the data that's referenced in your code
2. Moved **hasDeposit()** from being a **method** to **computed** (it only returns a calculated value)
3. Changed what's in **mounted**

I hope this is what you were after.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!